# Performing a right trim against a string

Tags: regex, perl

I'm attempting to perform the equivalent of a simple right trim in Perl using a regex.

I have the value `'1445:'` assigned to the string `$test`, I'm attempting to trim the colon from the end.

I have the following code which attempts to trim the colon, with this code `$test` is still set to `'1445:'` however. Can anyone suggest what the issue is here?

```
my $test = '1445:';
$test =~ s/:$//;
```

Comment: It works for me. Is that your *exact* (copy-and-pasted) code?

Comment: You probably have trailing whitespace. The code you've shown works: `perl -le'$test = "1445:"; $test =~ s/:$//; print $test'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't be the code you ran because it works.

```
$ perl -e'
    my $test = "1445:";
    $test =~ s/:$//;
    print "$test\n";
'
1445
```

Perhaps `$test` contained in the code you ran was different. Check with

```
use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
warn(Dumper($test));
```

Comment: Thanks. After some head scratching it appears my scripts seem to (somewhat inconstantly) cache themselves on the server.